# How to write a program testing the bandwidth between CPU and Memory?(Using C or C++)

Tags: c

follow my question title.
And I realize it using the code below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define COFF (1 << 20) //1MB
#define LOW_BYTE (1 << 10) //1kb
#define UP_BYTE (1 << 23) //8MB     
#define MAX UP_BYTE/sizeof(double)

double a[MAX] = {1};

double current_time(void)
{
    double timestamp;

    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, 0);

    timestamp = (double)((double)(tv.tv_sec*1e6) +(double)tv.tv_usec);
    return timestamp;
}

void test_band_width(int size){
    int i;
    volatile double r = 0;
    for (i=0; i < size; i+=16) {
        r += a[i]; 
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int k, size;
    double cycles;
    double t_start=0.0, t_end=0.0, time=0.0;
    for (k=UP_BYTE; k >= LOW_BYTE; k >>= 1) {
        size = k / sizeof(double);
        t_start = current_time();
        test_band_width(size);
        t_end = current_time();
        //printf("time is %lf\n",t_end-t_start);
        time = (t_end-t_start);
        printf("time2 is %lf\n\n\n",time);
        printf("This time the BandWith is %.7f\n",k/(16*time));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But there may be some problem when I tested my PC, maybe the way I test the systime?

Comment: There may be a problem.  There may not.  Why don't we start with what you think the problem might be and take it from there?

Comment: `gettimeofday()` returns milliseconds. Try `clock_gettime()` for nanoseconds: a 1000x increase in accuracy.

Comment: Might this program fit entirely within the CPU Cache?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do bandwidth tests and they all measures different things.  Search for the stream benchmarks for instance or look at http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf which gives pointer to some other tool.

One basic test is to have an inner loop like:

```
void** ptr = ...;

while (ptr != NULL) {
    ptr = (void**)*ptr;
}
```

and initialize your memory beforehand with the access pattern you want to test.  (Measure for instance with different stride, going forward/backward,...)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your target platform, using floating-point types such as `double` can significantly interfere with the performance you're trying to measure. I'd change your code to use pure integer operations throughout.

Comment: why double is bad? My pc is 15-inch macbook pro.

Comment: Some platforms - phones, for example - may not have hardware floating-point support, so floating-point calculations can really slow things down. If it's a PC or Mac you're testing on, then it's not really a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are expert timings for these things, with code, here: http://www.agner.org/optimize/#testp

That site is well worth a read - you may get your numbers there, rather than writing or running your own tests!